# An example of a function $g(x,y)$ such that $\frac{g(x,y)}{g(x,u)}$ never depends on $x$ but $g(x,y)\neq g_1(x)g_2(y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Is it possible to find a real continuous function $g(x,y)$ on $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ that depends explicitly on $x$ and $y$ and never equal to $0$ such that $\frac{g(x,y)}{g(x,u)}$ never depends on $x$ regardless of $x,y,u$ but we cannot separate the variables of $g$, i.e $g(x,y)\neq g_1(x)g_2(y)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is "no, it's always separable."

By the hypothesis, applied to $u = \frac12$, we have, for any $0\le x \le 1$,
$$
\frac{g(x, y)}{g(x, \frac12)} = \frac{g(\frac12, y)}{g(\frac12, \frac12)}.
$$
Multiplying through by $g(x, \frac12)$, we get

$$
g(x, y) = g(x, \frac12) \cdot \frac{g(\frac12, y)}{g(\frac12, \frac12)}.
$$
and letting $g_1(x) = g(x, \frac12)$, while $g_2(y) = \frac{g(\frac12, y)}{g(\frac12, \frac12)}$
we have $g(x, y) = g_1(x) g_2(y)$, so $g$ is in fact separable.